# Is OS Kernel a Daemon process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Is Kernel a Daemon ?
 Is raising a trap (by INT instruction) the only way to communicate with the kernel ?
 Do all system calls which call kernel subroutines, raise INT traps ?
 Does a user app runs in a different process than the kernel daemon, the user process being spawned by the kernel daemon ?

Comment: Kernel is not a Daemon - Neither it can run behalf of a process nor it can be scheduled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is raising a trap (by INT instruction) the only way to communicate with the kernel ?

No.  First, `INT` is an old mechanism for traps, most OSes now use `SYSENTER` on x86 and x86_64 platforms.  Other architectures have various types of software interrupt/trap instructions.

And a trap is not the only way to communicate with the kernel.  Since the kernel can access any memory, including that assigned to user-mode processes, shared memory is quite viable.

> Do all system calls which call kernel subroutines, raise INT traps?

The way to "call" kernel routine is with a trap (`SYSENTER`).  Other mechanisms such as shared memory queue data for the kernel to process but you wouldn't really say that is a subroutine call.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Kernel a Daemon ?

Nope.

> Is raising a trap (by INT instruction) the only way to communicate with the kernel ?

Yes, because the kernel and the userspace application are in a different privilege level, called rings. The kernel is running is supervisor mode, called ring0, while user applications run in ring3 called usermode.

> Do all system calls which call kernel subroutines, raise INT traps ?

Yes, they do.

> Does a user app runs in a different process than the kernel daemon, the user process being spawned by the kernel daemon ?

I don't really understand this, please elaborate.

Comment: The possible means of kernel entry vary by architecture; which of the possibilities (when there are more than one) a given operating system uses are a design decision.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I think newer AMD and Intel machines have a new syscall instruction that is more efficient than the whole `int` thing.

Comment: Yes, they have the SYSENTER / SYSEXIT situation, but that is more arch specific, and most OSes still use the INT instruction to trap into R0.

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea of processes, daemons, and such is an abstraction created by the kernel. At the CPU level, there are only two levels of division. There are processor cores, which run their code in parallel, and there privilege rings, which determine what instructions can be used.

The kernel runs in ring0 (and sometimes some drivers live in rings 1 and 2). Userspace code runs in ring3. Special processor mechanisms, such as interrupts or sysenter instructions are necessary to transfer control from ring3 code (userspace processes) to ring0 code (kernel).